# I need to create a map from an farm object list using the salary from Emploee class

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

This is the code I wrote so far for the other things I need to do. The main problem is that even with so much info I can't understand how to do it.

Create a map from the farm list which has like key the salary and like value the list of employee that has that salary. Display the map content, and for each employee display the farm in which is working

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
private String name;
private Integer salary;

public Employee (String name , Integer salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + salary;
}
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    return this.salary.compareTo(emp.getSalary());
}
```

}

Farm class

```
public class Farm {
private String name;
private Integer surface;

List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();


public Farm(String name , Integer surface) {
    this.name =  name;
    this.surface = surface;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setSurface(Integer surface) {
    this.surface = surface;
}
public int getSurface () {
    return surface;
}
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + surface;
}
public void makeList(String ename , Integer esalary) {
    this.emp.add(new Employee(ename,esalary));
}
public void getList() {
    for(Employee el : emp)
        System.out.println(el);
}
public Employee getMostPaidEmployee() {
    return Collections.max(emp);
}
```

}

And my main one

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List <Farm> FarmList = new ArrayList<Farm>();

    Farm farm1 = new Farm("Tiguana" , 700);
    farm1.makeList("Mihai", 30000);
    farm1.makeList("Vladimir", 4000);
    farm1.makeList("Tusnic", 3000);
    farm1.getList();

    System.out.println(farm1.getMostPaidEmployee());

    Farm farm2 = new Farm("Tipirei" , 800);
    farm2.makeList("Mihai", 30000);
    farm2.makeList("Mihail", 40000);
    farm2.makeList("Armando", 50000);
    farm2.makeList("ASihai", 60000);

    System.out.println(farm2.getMostPaidEmployee());

    FarmList.add(farm2);
    FarmList.add(farm1);


}
```

Comment: Tip: The term “make” in `makeList` suggests instantiating a whole new list, which is not what you are doing. A better name for that method would be `addEmployee`. Or ever just `add` as the required argument type of `Employee` makes it obvious.

Comment: Tip: Follow the Java coding conventions, it will help you read your code. So `List <Farm> FarmList` should be `List <Farm> farmList`. An initial uppercase letter means a *class* whereas an initial lowercase letter means an *instance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you gonna do it :

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Farm f : FarmList){
  for(Employee e : f.emp){
    if(!map.containsKey(e.salary)){
      map.put(e.salary, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(e.salary).add(e);
  }
}
```

Be sure to add the field of FarmName to your employee and override toString() method in Employee class so you can display what's asked.

Answer (score 2):

## `Map< Integer , List< Employee > >`

Sounds like you want to build a `Map< Integer , List< Employee > >`. The *key*, of type [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) (object, not primitive `int`), is the salary. The *value* is a `List` of employees with that particular salary.

So you need to instantiate such a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), probably a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html), or perhaps a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html). Then as you loop the employees, you see if their salary has already been added as a key to the map. If not, add the salary as a key, and create an empty `List` object as the value. Add that particular employee to the new list. If the salary is already present, retrieve the list, add the employee.

To report by farm, you need to find which farm hired that employee. You will loop the keys of the map, for each key retrieve its list of employees, and then loop those employees. For each employee, loop all the farms, and retrieve each farm’s list of employees, and see if the target employee is in that list. If so, you know the farm of the employee in the list on the map.

One flaw in your code is defining a `compareTo` on `Employee` by salary. Intuitively we can tell that does not smell right. You should instead have an identifier on each employee, like most any company assigns an “employee id” to each person hired. For the sake of your exercise, I would just use a `UUID` as the id. Add a member field of type `UUID` to your `Employee` class. Define `compareTo` using that object.

As this is obviously homework, I think I have said enough. You should be able to figure this out following my prose. You can also search Stack Overflow for many many examples of maps with a list as the value, and other such issues.

In real work, we would likely be concerned with [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) issues. But I assume that was not intended as part of your school assignment.

See also the coding-style tips I posted as Comments on the Question.